# JS & Jquery: if statement run even tho the terms of the statement are not true

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simon game and I ran through a problem that just randomly occurred (it worked fine before). After the `showColorStart()` function executes and you click on the given color, the if statement on line 33 runs, even though `colorsClicked[index]` is equal to `colorsPicked[index]`, and the statement needs to run when they are not equal.

Here's the code [on Codepen](https://codepen.io/WackThat/pen/oeVVNP).

```js
// Setting Variables
var gameStatus = false;
var strict = false;
var playerTurn = true;
var colors = ['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
var colorsPicked = [];
var colorsClicked = [];
var level = 1;
var index = -1;
var lindex = 0;
var showOn = false;
// Game Status Function
$('#start').click(function(){
    if(gameStatus == false){
        gameStatus = true;
        gameStart();
    }
});
// Game Start Function
function gameStart(){

}
// Chaning color buttons
$('.cubes').click(function(e){
    if(playerTurn = true){
        index++;
        $(e.target).addClass(e.target.id);
        colorsClicked.push(e.target.id);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(e.target).removeClass(e.target.id);
        }, 500);
        // Player's turn & check if got the right colors
        if(colorsClicked[index] !== colorsPicked[index]){
            index=0;
            lindex=0;
            alert('Failed! Try again.');
            showColorStart();
        } else {
            if(colorsPicked.length == colorsClicked.length){
                level++;
                randomColor();
                showColorStart();
            }
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
// Random Color Picking Function
function randomColor(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    colorsPicked.push(colors[random]);
}
// Colors Showing at Start of a level
function showColorStart(){
 if(!showOn){
    showOn == true;
    playerTurn = false;
    lindex = 0;
    var colorLoop = setInterval(function(){
        if(colorsPicked[lindex] == 'green'){
        $('#green').addClass('green');
    } else if(colorsPicked[lindex] == 'red'){
        $('#red').addClass('red');
    } else if(colorsPicked[lindex] == 'yellow'){
        $('#yellow').addClass('yellow');
    } else if(colorsPicked[lindex] == 'blue'){
        $('#blue').addClass('blue');
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#green').removeClass('green');
        $('#red').removeClass('red');
        $('#yellow').removeClass('yellow');
        $('#blue').removeClass('blue');
    }, 500);
    lindex++;
    if(lindex == colorsPicked.length){
        clearInterval(colorLoop);
        showOn = false;
        lindex = 0;
        index = 0;
        colorsClicked = [];
        $('#disp').html('Your Turn!');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#disp').html('');
        }, 1000);
        playerTurn = true;
    }
    }, 1500);
 } else {
     return;
 }
}
randomColor();
randomColor();
showColorStart();
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simon Game</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href='bootstrap.min.css' type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <input type='button' value='Start' id='start' class='btn'>
    <input type='button' value='Restart' id='restart' class='btn'>
    <input type='button' value='Strict' id='strict' class='btn'>
  </div>
  <div class='board'>
    <div class='display'><p id='disp'></p></div>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class='cubes' id='green'></td>
          <td class='cubes' id='red'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='cubes' id='yellow'></td>
          <td class='cubes' id='blue'></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: @SatishKumar the if statement on line 33 is the fail condition to the simon game, if the player clicked the wrong color, this if statement will run, now the problem is that the if statement is running even if you click on the right color.

Comment: When I click on start I see no colors. By the way I can see you are using **showOn == true;** instead of = . Also Here **if(playerTurn = true)** you must be using == for comparison.

Comment: Why is your gameStart() blank?

Comment: @SatishKumar im leaving that for later, im now focusing on the game functions it self, and im sorry i didnt link the codepen, im editing the post to add the codepen link.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison. You have `if(playerTurn = true){`

Comment: It is because the index is 1 and the colour is the first one in the array which is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you increment your index before getting to the if. Put the increment at the end and it works perfectly.

```
$('.cubes').click(function(e){
    if(playerTurn = true){
        $(e.target).addClass(e.target.id);
        colorsClicked.push(e.target.id);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(e.target).removeClass(e.target.id);
        }, 500);
        // Player's turn & check if got the right colors
        if(colorsClicked[index] !== colorsPicked[index]){
            index=0;
            lindex=0;
            alert('Failed! Try again.');
            showColorStart();
        } else {
            if(colorsPicked.length == colorsClicked.length){
                level++;
                randomColor();
                showColorStart();
            }
        }
        index++;
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Arrays start at 0

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two things, you must use a comparison operator (>, ==, ===, <)

You used an assignment operator "=" which will not compare two objects but actually try to assign (the value of the 2nd to the 1st).

Try swapping your single 'equals sign' with a double 'equals sign. Also, it may need double quotes around the value. Hope this helps.